# Your wordpress server appears to be overloaded. [SOLVED]

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, gatsby-image, wp-graphql

I'm getting the error below when trying to call `gatsby develop`.

```
 ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental_111007 

 gatsby-source-wordpress  Your wordpress server at http://localwp/graphql appears to be overloaded

Try reducing the requestConcurrency for content updates or the previewRequestConcurrency for previews:

{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental',
  options: {
    schema: {
      requestConcurrency: 5, // currently set to 5
      previewRequestConcurrency: 2, // currently set to 2
    }
  },
}

The GATSBY_CONCURRENT_REQUEST environment variable is no longer used to control concurrency.
If you were previously using that, you'll need to use the settings above instead.
```

I tried to set requestConcurrency: 5 and previewRequestConcurrency: 2 as suggested but it was not enough.

Things I did before getting error appeared that may be related:

- I updated the `WPGraphQL` plugin (v1.1.1) today (I tried to downgrade to v1.1.0 but the problem persists)
- I set `useGatsbyImage` (within the 'gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental' options in gatsby-config.js) to false to do some tests.

Plugins used on Wordpress are: `WP Gatsby (v0.9.1)`,  `WP GraphQL (v1.1.0)`, `WP GraphQL Gutenberg (v0.3.5)`.

I'm running a local wordpress server (via Local) and it seems to be working normally.

[SOLVED] : I disabled WP GraphQL Gutenberg (v0.3.5) and it started to work again. Looks like this plugin might be overloading the wordpress server.

Comment: Have you tried using lower values for `requestConcurrency`?

Comment: Hi Ferran! Yes, i tried to set value 1 for both. I looking forward to see if it's a problem on the Local's server.

Comment: I disabled `WP GraphQL Gutenberg (v0.3.5)` and it started to work again. This plugin might be overloading the wordpress server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] : I disabled WP GraphQL Gutenberg (v0.3.5) and it started to work again. Looks like this plugin might be overloading the wordpress server. It's probably some incompatibility between `WP GraphQL (v1.1.0)` and WP `GraphQL Gutenberg (v0.3.5)`. More information about this incompatibility [here](https://github.com/pristas-peter/wp-graphql-gutenberg/issues/72).